# JavaScript file stopped working on the last Chrome version

Tags: javascript, mime-types

We have an old page. Recently Google Chrome (and other last version browsers) stopped showing menu , but if I hit "refresh", than Inspect Tool shows the following error:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: ".../menu.js.php"

What could be the solution for this problem, or the problem is actually elsewhere?

Comment: Could you drop your script here? Maybe with a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Javascript files are actually PHP files, the server transfers the file as *text/html*. I did not find this out myself. I took it from [SCRIPTONITE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973146/2119245)

To set a header in PHP, you can use the [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. You should always set the headers as early as possible to avoid errors. You may only set headers if you have not yet sent anything to the output. No echo, not HTML, nothing. From the manual:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

To set the header for a Javascript file, use this line:

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because the header content type is not being set correctly by the server:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

To clarify, your server should set the correct http header on the response to reflect the content type.

I guess in your page you have a script tag with type="text/javascript" but Chrome is saying the server is not identifying the content as javascript.

Comment: can I change it in the index.php file or should I do it elsewhere?

Comment: I would do it at the server level. So Apache or IIS most probably in your case in the config file, eg for Apache -> httpd.conf? So any request to a file with a .js extension should have a response with the correct content type

Comment: The extension is .js.php, so I guess it's better to set the content-type in PHP with `header("Content-Type: application/javascript")`

Comment: As I understood - our hosting company already did it 1/2 hour ago, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Butt4cak3 ah yes, so you could do it at the php level. However, I think it belies a fundamental content negotiation problem with the server config, so I would try and set it on the global level to resolve any future issues.

Comment: @Robert002 perhaps there is a propagation delay on the changes being reflected across the servers used? Maybe you need to wait for a small period of time longer before seeing the difference

Comment: @Butt4cak3 do I have to add `header("Content...` to index.php file or should I do it somewhere else?

Comment: @Robert002 It belongs in the .js.php files.

Comment: @Robert002 It should work to put it in the top most PHP section. I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Butt4cak3 could you please make your first comment as a separate answer so I could accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

the `Content-Type` this is not the problem.

the problem is elsewhere. A problem that I see is with fancybox:

jQuery from version 1.9 has removed most if not all of the depreciated methods.

$.browser was one of them. Fancybox relies on $.browser, so you can't use jQuery 1.9 or maior  and your version of fancybox without the migrate plugin installed.

You can downgrade jQuery to a version < 1.9 or upgrade fancybox to version 2 or include the [jquery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

Comment: @Robert002 read my updated answer. anyway if javascript brokes than it stop to parse other javascript

Comment: @Robert002 you should isolate your menu javascripts code and create a jsfiddle. it is too hard to test from your webpage

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem is - it's not built by me, but I'll try to disect the menu part to jsfiddle